# jconnect support ASE 15.0.3

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I need to connect to Sybase version 15.0.3 through a java program using JDBC. I got to know that I have to install jconnect to get the JDBC drivers for Sybase. 
Where can I download jconnect? Since the following links does not work anymore:
http://www.sybase.com/products/middleware/jconnectforjdbc
http://downloads.sybase.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According this document [jConnect Drivers description](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/jConnect+Driver) you can get either jConnect v6 which should be part of Sybase ASE 15.03 installation (choose custom and select jConnect) or you can get jConnect v7 from package called "SY SOFTWARE DEVELOPER KIT 15.7" (SDK) from [SAP lauchpad](https://support.sap.com/software.html) (search under software downloads - you have to have user account authorized for downloads).

Both versions are compatible, however each of them have separate documentation under Sybase infocenter